# Dot syntax and nested html forms. Unable to fetch data during testing

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am new to the Laravel. I have not tried this in browser I am using tests for this.

I have test that looks like this:

```
public function testStoreRequestValid()
{
    $data = [
        'name' => 'New Item',
        'parameter.count' => '3',
        'parameter.0.parameter_id' => '4',
        'parameter.0.value_id' => '',
        'parameter.0.value' => 'text',
        'parameter.1.parameter_id' => '1',
        'parameter.1.value_id' => '2',
        'parameter.1.value' => 'Yes',
        'parameter.2.parameter_id' => '2',
        'parameter.2.value_id' => '',
        'parameter.2.value' => '10'
    ];

    $response = $this->call('post', '/item', $data);

    // ...
}
```

When I try to fetch data using:

```
$parameterCount = $request->input('parameter.count');
```

I get null value (if I use has method it gets false).

When I have tried to use square brackets I have got the results, but I want the API to be usable with JSON too without too much hastle in the JS.

How do I solve this in the most clean way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dot in Laravel has a special meaning so you can't really use arrays which have dots in their keys. You should declare your data as follows:

```
<?php
$data = [];
array_set($data,'name','New Item');    
array_set($data,'parameter.count','3');
array_set($data,'parameter.0.parameter_id','4');
array_set($data,'parameter.0.value_id','');
array_set($data,'parameter.0.value','text');
array_set($data,'parameter.1.parameter_id','1');
array_set($data,'parameter.1.value_id','2');
array_set($data,'parameter.1.value','Yes');
array_set($data,'parameter.2.parameter_id','2');
array_set($data,'parameter.2.value_id','');
array_set($data,'parameter.2.value','10');
```

Comment: I do understand this approach, but will Laravel treat such data similarly when they will be sent by post request?
[Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#validating-arrays) says it should work, but this not explaining how it should work. It is so vague that I am left with guessing. Does it expect square brackets or dots?

Comment: Check https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/requests#retrieving-input specifically where it mentions *When working on forms with array inputs, you may use "dot" notation to access the arrays*

Comment: It does not work in tests if there is something like `'parameter[count]' => '3'` and trying to retrieve it with `$request->input('parameter.count')` it does not work I get _null_ whenever I have tried it.

Edit: It does not even pass validation.

Comment: You input needs to look like : `[ parameter => [ count => 3 ] ]` in order to be able to get it via `$request->input("parameter.count")` in tests. That is equivalent to `<input name="parameter[count]" value='3' type="hidden" />` (or similar).

Comment: Sorry for nuisance. I could not find any mention of this in documentation regarding tests.

Comment: @yad I don't think it's documented. The array dot notation itself isn't that well documented either except for the [helper function documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers) (specifically `array_get` and `array_set` )

Comment: There is clearly explanation, but tests could use explanation how they interact with other stuff. The important: thanks a lot for your help.